# Limit number of concurrent threads multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to apply a function to every element of an iterable with a fixed number of threads (let’s say N) running concurrently, like multiprocessing.ThreadPool.map() does, but my function does assignments to global objects and does not return anything. How can I limit number of concurrent threads without using map and wasting memory for a list of Nones?

```
def function(x):
    print(x)
    # do some actions, don't return anything

iterable = list(range(1000_000))

import multiprocessing.pool as mp
import os

N = os.cpu_count()

with mp.ThreadPool(N) as pool:
    _ = pool.map(function, iterable)
    # returns unnecessary list of Nones
```

Comment: If you include some code on what you are doing or what you think you should do it may help you to get a better answer.

Comment: Ok, added an edit with some example code